# Why my app is rejected reason "Restore Purchases" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased in-app purchases

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am not getting why my app is rejected even i have used the restore purchase code in the in-app purchase . Please tell me where i am wrong below is my code:-

```
public typealias ProductIdentifier = String
public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()

open class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

  static let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"
  fileprivate let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
  fileprivate var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<ProductIdentifier>()
  fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
  fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

  public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
    productIdentifiers = productIds
    for productIdentifier in productIds {
      let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
      if purchased {
        purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
        print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
      } else {
        print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
      }
    }
    super.init()
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
  }

}

// MARK: - StoreKit API

extension IAPHelper {

  public func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
    productsRequest?.cancel()
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest!.delegate = self
    productsRequest!.start()
  }

  public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
    print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
  }

  public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
    return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
  }

  public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
  }

  public func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
  }
}

// MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

  public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let products = response.products
    print("Loaded list of products...")
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
    clearRequestAndHandler()

    for p in products {
      print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
    }
  }

  public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to load list of products.")
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
    clearRequestAndHandler()
  }

  private func clearRequestAndHandler() {
    productsRequest = nil
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
  }
}

// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

  public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
      switch (transaction.transactionState) {
      case .purchased:
        complete(transaction: transaction)
        break
      case .failed:
        fail(transaction: transaction)
        break
      case .restored:
        restore(transaction: transaction)
        break
      case .deferred:
        break
      case .purchasing:
        break
      }
    }
  }

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for: SKProduct) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

  private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("complete...")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
  }

  private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

    print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
    deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

  }

  private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("fail...")
    if let transactionError = transaction.error as? NSError {
      if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
        print("Transaction Error: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription)")
      }
    }

    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
  }

  private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
    guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

    purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
  }
}
```

Comment: But does your app's user interface provide some sort of "Restore Purchases" button? The code in your question has nothing to do with Apple's rejection.

Comment: i have used this code before but that time i have not given any button of restore @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

You should adding such a **Restore purchases button** and the user should be able to see it in app interface.

you need not only to call 
`SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()` 
but implement the restoring itself too (i mean, providing the content to user).